# Do [贈]{おく}り物 and プレゼント mean the same thing?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, usage, loanwords

The use of loan words such as プレゼント are used much more just like カメラ is and such. So should i just disregard [贈]{おく}り物 and focus my memory on something else or do you know if [贈]{おく}り物 is still used and is important till this day?

Comment: Welcome to JSE!  Just FYI, we have formatting for furigana support.  Check it out [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/78).  I've gone ahead and edited your question to include it.

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick search for both headwords in two well-known corpora. The results are below:

**BCCWJ: (Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese)**

- 贈り物　668 entries
- プレゼント　3268 entries

**Tsukuba Web Corpus**

- 贈り物    5672 entries
- プレゼント   21974 entries

It seems that プレゼント is indeed more common than 贈り物. Having said that, 贈り物 shouldn't be considered a rare word and it appears to be in regular use, albeit less so than プレゼント. I would say that 贈り物 is probably a slightly more formal word perhaps, and so might be preferred in writing or formal styles. I wouldn't advise disregarding it as you may encounter it in some situations.